# Spring SimpleJDBCInsert - How to get generated keys on a batch insert?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

Suppose I insert ten rows to a table using batch update. I think it is possible to get all the ten generated keys using JDBC PreparedStatement method-

```
ResultSet getGeneratedKeys()
```

But how to achieve this with the spring framework? The SimpleJDBCInsert class has executeAndReturnKey() method, that works fine for one row insert at a time. But is there a way to do it for batch inserts ie., when using the executeBatch() method?

Comment: Which database are you using ? As for H2 database we will not get multiple keys

Comment: I am using mysql database, which supports multiple keys returning.